# Power BI Linear Regression DAX measure always returns 0 for slope

Tags: powerbi, linear-regression, dax, trendline

Hi and thanks for reading,

I am manually calculating a trend line in Power BI using linear regression.  I used the formula from here: https://xxlbi.com/blog/simple-linear-regression-in-dax/

My problem is that the numerator of the slope is always 0
(This--> (Count_Items * Sum_XY - Sum_X * Sum_Y)).

I have no idea why (count_items* Sum_XY) - (sum_x * sum_y) is always 0.

Here is my DAX formula I used:

```
measure = VAR Known =
    FILTER (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'table'[Date] ), ALLSELECTED ('table') ),
            //ALLSELECTED ( 'table'[Date] ),
            "Known[X]", value('table'[Date]),
            "Known[Y]", sum('table'[TotalPeople])
        ),
        AND (
            NOT ( ISBLANK ( Known[X] ) ),
            NOT ( ISBLANK ( Known[Y] ) )
        )
    )
VAR Count_Items =
    COUNTROWS ( Known )
VAR Sum_X =
    SUMX(Known,Known[X])
    
VAR Sum_X2 =
    SUMX ( Known, Known[X] ^ 2 )
VAR Sum_Y =
    SUMX ( Known, Known[Y] )
VAR Sum_XY =
    SUMX ( Known, Known[X] * Known[Y] )
VAR Average_X =
    AVERAGEX ( Known, Known[X] )
VAR Average_Y =
    AVERAGEX ( Known, Known[Y] )
VAR Slope =
    DIVIDE (
        (Count_Items * Sum_XY - Sum_X * Sum_Y),
        (Count_Items * Sum_X2 - Sum_X ^ 2)
    )
VAR Intercept =
    Average_Y - Slope * Average_X

//I am only returning the numerator of the slope because always being 0 ruins the equation.
RETURN
    Count_Items * Sum_XY - Sum_X * Sum_Y
```

Here is some example data from my table:

```
Date,TotalPeople
3/21/2020 12:00:00 AM,4
3/22/2020 12:00:00 AM,3
3/23/2020 12:00:00 AM,5
etc
```

Comment: I've implemented the same statement and it works ok in my use. What's the output of your 'known' table, I think the issue will be there

Comment: The problem is that Count_Items * Sum_XY is equal to Sum_X * Sum_Y.  Therefore when it is subtracted, it is equal to 0.  Any idea why that could possibly be true?